# Excel Dynamic Pivot Table

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

First of all let me say this site has helped me numerous times.  Now I'm stuck with something I haven't can't find a solution for.  I have a table in Microsoft Excel 2010.  PowerPivot is installed on the program.

I need to be able to input three items, let's say a customer, the beginning date range, and the end date range.

I have a table of data that contains this and all the possible dates in between.  I want to dynamically select those three inputs and have it display the sum of those items based on the customer and time frame.

I recognize (and appreciate) the use of a pivot table for this data but I'm looking for something someone without knowledge of the pivot table to input these figures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Slicers are a great way to do this. Try this:

1. Convert your data to a Table, `Insert>Tables>Table`
2. While a cell in your Table is highlighted, create a Pivot Table  `Insert>Tables>PivotTable`
3. Set your Pivot Tables Values = the value you want to Sum (e.g. Sales).
4. To filter based on Date and Customer, use slicers, `Insert>Filter>Slicer`.  Choose the columns you want to use for a filter (e.g. Date and Customer).
5. Now your end user can simply select the appropriate Dates (hold the shift key to hold multiple) and Customer for your needs.

If you want to select a Date Range (as opposed to the dates of interest) it takes a little more setup.  Do you want a constant set of ranges (e.g. 30, 60, 90 days) or does it need to be constantly variable?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  The slicer will be sufficient.